# Primefaces text in outputLabel pattern of réal

Tags: jsf, primefaces, entity, bean-validation

Is there any way to make a pattern to the value of `outputLabel`, I tried like this way :

```
@Digits(integer=3, fraction=2)
```

I put this annotation in my Entity but nothing is changed

Someone have an idea to chnage this number in ENTITY or in the page?

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{VarAvancementPrj.avancementprojet}%"/>

// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "avancementprojet", precision = 17, scale = 17)
@Digits(integer=3,fraction=2)
private Double avancementprojet;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add converter inside your outputlabel

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
```